# Angular Directive Interpreting attribute as string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My directive is the following

```
angular
    .module('app.directives')
    .directive('myTable',function(){

        function linkFn(
            scope,
            element,
            attrs
            ) {

            console.log(attrs.attributes);

        }

        return {
            link: linkFn,
            template: 'some.html',
            scope: {
                attributes: '=',
            },
            replace : true
        }
    });
```

And I use the directive as

```
<my-table attributes="management.table.attributes"></my-table>
```

However the `attrs.attribute` value in the link function resolves to the string `management.table.attributes`, instead of being an array.

I will appreciate any kind of help or guidance.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attrs.attribute` is always going to be a string, because attributes are strings by definition. You need corresponding `scope.attributes` which is going to be evaluated object reference:

```
console.log(scope.attributes);
```